# Decoding a random amount of strings into a message

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, state

This function should take a random amount of numbers represented in strings, parse them into ints and then replace each string with the correct letter of the alphabet which index is the result of input string % 27. Also when input % 27 == 0 it switches between lower and uppercase, and also when you pass an input%9==0 it switches to 'punctuation' mode to retrieve the corresponding punctuation character detailed in the getPunctuation function.

```
function compareToAlphabet(number, mode){
                const alphabetUpper = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
                const alphabetLower = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','i','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

                const index = parseNumber(number) - 1
                
                    let result = '';
                    if(mode=='uppercase'){
                        for (let i = 0; i <= alphabetUpper.length - 1; i++){
                        if (index === alphabetUpper.indexOf(alphabetUpper[i])){
                            result = alphabetUpper[i]
                            } 
                        } return result
                    }
                    if (mode=='lowercase'){
                        for (let i = 0; i <= alphabetLower.length - 1; i++){
                        if (index === alphabetLower.indexOf(alphabetLower[i])){
                            result = alphabetLower[i]
                            } 
                        } return result
                    }
                
            }
function getPunctuation(number){
                const index = parseNumber(number);
                let result = '' 
                    switch(index){
                        case 1: result = '!';
                        break;
                        case 2: result = '?';
                        break;
                        case 3: result = ',';
                        break;
                        case 4: result = '.';
                        break;
                        case 5: result = ' ';
                        break;
                        case 6: result = ';';
                        break;
                        case 7: result = '"';
                        break;
                        case 8: result = '\'';
                        break;  
                    } return result
                
            }
    function decoder(...args) {
    let resultArr = [];
    let mode = 'uppercase'; 

    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        let index = parseNumber(args[i]);
        function getLetter(index, mode) {
            
             
            // Update mode based on conditions
           
            if (index % 27 === 0 && mode === 'uppercase') {
                mode = 'lowercase';
            } else if (index % 27 === 0 && mode === 'lowercase') {
                mode = 'uppercase';
            } else if (index % 9 === 0 &&(mode === 'lowercase'||mode==='uppercase')){
                mode === 'punctuation'
            }
            if(mode === 'lowercase' || mode === 'uppercase'){
                return compareToAlphabet(index % 27, mode);
            }
            if(mode === 'punctuation'){
                return getPunctuation(index % 9)
            }
            
        }

        let emptyLetter = getLetter(index, mode)

        if (emptyLetter !== ''){//skips pushing empy strings
            resultArr.push(getLetter(index, mode));
        }

        mode = (index % 27 === 0 || index % 9 === 0) ? 
        ((mode === 'uppercase' || mode === 'lowercase') ? 'punctuation' : 
         (mode === 'punctuation' ? (index % 27 === 0 ? 'lowercase' : 'uppercase') : mode)) : mode;

    }
    
    return resultArr.join('');
}
```

`Ri"'?kr"es!` <--- this is the output I get
`Right?Yes!`  <--- this is the expected output

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your input to get that output? I suspect `%9 === 0` is the issue, since 9, 18 and 27 are 0 modulo 9

Comment: also, that `mode = (index % 27 === 0 || index % 9 === 0) ?  ((mode === 'uppercase' || mode === 'lowercase') ? 'punctuation' : .... etc` looks wrong

Comment: also, this `for (let i = 0; i <= alphabetUpper.length - 1; i++){` loop is ridiculous - you could just `return alphabetUpper[index]`

Comment: Your code can not produce the output you claim it does

Comment: The input is ('18','12312','171','763','98423','1208','216','11','500','18','241','0','32','20620','27','10'). And yeah, I know abt those loops

Comment: I forgot that I had a few other functions on top, like parseNum that only parses the strings.

Comment: wow, that's some weird encoding ... but the `171` results in the mode being punctuation for the next code - and `763`, `98423`, and `1208` do not switch back to non-punctuation

Comment: `else if (index % 9 === 0 &&(mode === 'lowercase'||mode==='uppercase')){
                mode === 'punctuation'
            }` does nothing, did you mean `mode = 'punctuation'` (won't fix the problem though)

Comment: Yes, I meant mode = punctuation, sorry

Comment: makes the output different though :p

Comment: There's no way the output can be limited to 10 characters ... I know there's 16 numbers in the input, and some numbers result in no output, but at least 11 (though more likely 12) characters will be output based on your logic

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.